# ANTLR4 - "Illegal Escape in String" expression for Lexer

Tags: string, antlr4, lexer

The requirement for the assignment is:

> "Illegal escape in string: " + wrong string: When the lexer detects an illegal
>   escape in string. The wrong string is from the beginning of the string to the
>   illegal escape.
>
> All the supported escape sequences are as follows:
>
> > \b backspace
> >
> > \f formfeed
> >
> > \r carriage return
> >
> > \n newline
> >
> > \t horizontal tab
> >
> > \’ single quote
> >
> > \" double quote
> >
> > \ backslash

I use the code for "String" as same as this post recommended:

[ANTLR4 - Need an explanation on this String Literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348288/antlr4-need-an-explanation-on-this-string-literals#)

```
STRINGLIT: '"' ( '\\' [btnfr"'\\] | ~[\b\t\f\r\n\\"] )* '"';
```

And also fix a little bit for "Unterminated (or Unclosed) String"  as follow:

```
UNCLOSE_STRING: '"' ( '\\' [btnfr"'\\] | ~[\b\t\f\r\n\\"] )* ;
```

So I tried to write down the prototype for that requirement like this:

```
ILLEGAL_ESCAPE: '"' .*? ESCAPE ;
fragment ESCAPE: [\b\f\r\n\t'"\\]
```

Can someone help me to figure out if had done something wrong to it, I think there is something not clear between STRING and ILLEGAL_ESCAPE so the result is not right.
I appreciate if you can fix it again to meet the requirement as I mentioned earlier. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the following lexer rule:

```
ILLEGAL_ESCAPE: '"' ('\\' ~[btnfr"'\\] | ~'\\')*;
```

Comment: I think your solution is pretty good but can you explain more about your lexer rule vs my lexer rule. Thanks alot^^

Comment: Your fragment rule `ESCAPE` is not correct. It matches not two-symbol sequences (backslash + char) but just a single special symbols (`\r`, `\b`, etc.). Whereas my lexer rule matches all two-symbol sequences start with a backslash and all sequences that do not contain backslashes.